# Have to add a simple condition in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twilio

I have to setup my rails project to send a confirmation SMS to new users. I have a table phone_calling_codes which has a column sms_enable_flag. In my DB this field has to be checked or not, so it's boolean.

I use Twilio to send SMS but I want to add a condition to send SMS only to the numbers where this sms_enable_flag is checked.

I also use phonelib to parse the number and take the country code from it.

```
def perform(phone_number, confirmation_code)

     logger.info("Job started sending confirmation code")

     overrideToPhone = [ "development","upgrade"].include? Rails.env
     deliverSMS = !([ "development", "upgrade"].include? Rails.env)


     phone=''
     if overrideToPhone
       e164Prefix = '+'
       phone_number = e164Prefix  + "17782002024"
     else
       phone = Phonelib.parse( phone_number)
       phone_number = phone.e164
     end

     sms=phone_calling_codes.find_by calling_code: phone.country_code
     if sms
      if sms.sms_enabled_flag
        from_phone_number =  Rails.application.secrets.twilio_number
        body = "Valorbit.com - your phone verification code is: #{confirmation_code}"

        logger.info("From #{from_phone_number} to #{phone_number} : #{body}")

        twilio_client.messages.create(
            to: phone_number ,
            from: from_phone_number ,
            body: body
        ) if deliverSMS
        logger.info("Sent sms to #{phone_number}") if deliverSMS
      else
        logger.info("SMS is not enabled for  #{phone_number}")
      end

     end
  end
```

Please help me to this. I am a beginner to OOP and I want to understand if it is ok how I have thought.

Thanks! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change line

```
sms=phone_calling_codes.find_by calling_code: phone.country_code
```

to

```
sms=PhoneCallingCode.find_by calling_code: phone.country_code
```

`PhoneCallingCode` is the model name present in `/app/models` folder

Below is the query to find data from model:

```
ModelName.find_by column_name: parameter
```